# can i use windows workflow 4 for an asp.net 3.5 app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I already have an application built in asp.net 3.5 and now I want to migrate to windows workflow for business logic. I liked wf 4 but the point is can I use it with my asp.net 3.5 app or am I stuck with  wf 3.5 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use in in the same process but there is nothing preventing you from using a Workflow Service hosted in a .NET 4 AppDomain.